# I tried for many hours to come up with a query but I don't even know if this is possible to have information from different rows in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sample table that stores information as follows: The two sub-systems are mini1 and mini2

| System | Date | Sub System | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| primary | 2022-05-11 | mini1 | 103 |
| secondary | 2022-05-11 | mini2 | 100 |
| secondary | 2022-05-11 | mini1 | 10 |
| backup | 2022-05-11 | mini2 | 95 |
| backup | 2022-05-11 | mini1 | 11 |
| primary | 2022-05-11 | mini2 | 15 |
| primary | 2022-04-01 | mini1 | 0 |
| secondary | 22022-04-01 | mini2 | 0 |
| secondary | 2022-04-01 | mini1 | 100 |
| backup | 2022-04-01 | mini2 | 0 |
| backup | 2022-04-01 | mini1 | 110 |
| primary | 2022-04-01 | mini2 | 0 |

I want to get the latest information on each system in a format such as follows, where only the latest date is considered.

| System | Latest Date | mini1 Count | mini 2 Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| primary | 2022-05-11 | 103 | 15 |
| secondary | 2022-05-11 | 10 | 100 |
| backup | 2022-05-11 | 11 | 95 |

Is this possible through sql?

Comment: what is the question? what results are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` _expressions_ to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: @Esther updated the table so its more readable. Subquery in what sense? in the select clause?

Comment: No need for a subquery.

Comment: @jarlh is there an example? I have not used case expressions in the past

Comment: @jarlh true, I was too hasty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5Dconditional+aggregation+case

Comment: @jarlh I see what you're saying, but I don't need to do aggregation in this query. Just need to pull in appropriate cells and append to new rows based on latest date

Comment: You can also do self joins, but GROUP BY is easier, and will perform better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*.

```
select System,
       max(Date) LatestDate,
       sum(case when SubSystem = 'mini1' then count else 0 end) Mini1Count,
       sum(case when SubSystem = 'mini2' then count else 0 end) Mini2Count
from tablename
group by System
```